# Get packets byte from filter using command line

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I looking for command that after search for specific filter for example: `tcp.port==80` the output will be the packet in byte.

until now i am using this command : `tshark.exe -Y tcp.port==80 -n -r file.pcap`
and the output is only the packet details:

```
packet number  28.853596  192.0.16.37 -> 66.196.114.114 TCP 66 50580 > 5050 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add -x option to your command: `tshark.exe -Y tcp.port==80 -x -n -r file.pcap`